# Is there a word for when a song leaves out a word or phrase despite it perfectly fitting?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

I'm gonna be honest, I've been hearing my fair share of Steven Universe music from devices I'm not in control of from across the room. In a few songs I've noticed they will leave out a word but I could tell you exactly what word was implied and I had to see if anyone knew a term for it.

For example, in the song "Strong in the real way", comes this excerpt: "... can't you see she's out of control and overzealous? I'm telling you for your own good, and not because I'm- " and it cuts out there despite it very clearly implying the word "jealous".

I hope this is detailed enough that someone will be able to know what I'm talking about. I've looked for this on Google but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: "I am just a poor boy though my story's seldom told
I have squandered my resistance for a pocket full of g̶o̶l̶d̶ mumbles"

Comment: @Peter Nobody expects the Resistance. Is there a connection to the Boxer Rebellion?

Comment: Thank you for being honest.

Answer (score 3):

This has been called mind rhyme, subverted rhyme, or teasing rhyme. See [this stackexchange answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168461/is-there-a-word-or-concise-phrase-for-this-word-play) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subverted_rhyme).

[Note: I discovered this was a duplicate after posting my answer; I'm going to apologize, but I don't see why I should delete it]